# Como arrojar excepciones usando operador ternario en Python

Tags: python, poo, excepciones

Quiero arrojar una excepción en una sola línea a un método que tiene que recibir un boleano en caso que no lo reciba, mediante el uso de un operador ternario. Como puedo hacerlo? Traté de colocarle un **`else pass`** pero no me valida la sintaxis

```
def metodo(self,boleano):
        try:
            raise ValueError('Se esperaba un boleano') if not isinstance(boleano, bool) else pass
            #Implementar el resto del metodo

        except ValueError as errorPropio:
            print(errorPropio)
```

**Nota:** Se como implementarlo en más lineas y funciona. Quiero que el `raise` funcione en una sola, gracias

Comment: No entiendo el requisito de una sola línea, pero esto funcionaría: `if not isinstance(booleano, bool): raise ValueError('Se esperaba un booleano')`. Por cierto que también te sobraría el `try:` en delante de esa línea, pues de lo contrario la excepción que lanzas la estás capturando luego. A menos que eso sea lo que pretendes.

Comment: Pretendo capturar la excepción que lanzo, eso funciona pero requiero usar esta sintaxis `raise ValueError('etc') if algo else otracosa` y quería saber si era posible. Gracias por responder. Hasta ahora, me quedo con tu respuesta

Comment: He borrado mis anteriores comentarios porque estaban mal. He añadido una respuesta explicando por qué.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuidado, la expresión que buscas en realidad no hace lo que esperas.

La sintaxis "ternaria" `a if b else c` requiere que tanto `a` como `b`, como `c` sean expresiones, esto es, tengan un valor (el de `b` se interpretará por el contexto como booleano). Está pensado para ser usado al lado derecho de una asignación, como en:

```
r = a if b else c
```

Ni `a`, ni `b`, ni `c` pueden ser comandos, sino expresiones (una llamada a una función cuenta como expresión, puesto que retorna un valor y entonces se usaría el valor retornado).

`raise` no es una expresión. Es un comando. Por eso esto no funciona:

```
r = raise Exception() if b else c
```

Ni esto:

```
r = a if b else raise Exception()
```

Ni esto:

```
a if b else raise Exception()
```

---

Entonces ¿Cómo es que funciona esto?

```
raise Exception() if b else c
```

Pues porque Python lo está viendo así:

```
raise (Exception() if b else c)
```

Es decir, el operador ternario se está aplicando para decidir qué excepción se eleva, y no para decidir si se eleva o no una excepción. Si `b` es evaluado como cierto, se elevará la excepción `Exception()` y si no, la excepción resultado de evaluar `c`.

Si intentas:

```
raise ValueError('Se esperaba un boleano') if not isinstance(boleano, bool) else None
```

entonces si no tienes el boolano se elevará `ValueError()`, pero si tienes el booleano se intentará elevar `None`, que no es una excepción válida y causará a su vez otra excepción `TypeError` (*exceptions must derive from BaseException*)

La forma recomendada por tanto sería:

```
if not isinstance(boleano, bool): raise ValueError('Se esperaba un boleano')
```

que también es una sola línea y más legible.

Answer (score 2):

```
def error():raise ValueError('Se esperaba un boleano')

def metodo(booleano):
    try:
        isinstance(booleano, bool) or error()
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
```

Definimos una funcion que lanza un error `def error():` y en el `metodo` verificamos que el argumento `booleano` sea una instancia de `bool` con el metodo `isinstance(booleano, bool)` dicho metodo retorna una `True` en caso de que si sea una instancia y `False` en caso contrario. Y con el Operador `or` verificamos, en caso de que `isinstance(booleano, bool)` sea `False` se ejecuta la funcion `error()`